# Как удалить лишние плюсы, чтобы был только один?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="subtotal">
    <script>$(".subtotal").text (Math.round( 50+50++50+70+50+50+++50 ) );</script>
</div>
```

Как удалить лишние плюсы, чтобы был только один?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как удалить лишние плюсы, чтобы был только один?

Можно вот так.

```js
let s = '50+50++50+70+50+50+++50'
s = s.split(/\++/).reduce((s, v) => +v + s, 0)
document.querySelector('.subtotal').textContent = s
```

```html
<div class="subtotal"></div>
```

Comment: Почему на странице выводится `NaN` а в консоли нормально `$(".subtotal").text (Math.round( m ) );`

Comment: Я в строке убрал лишние плюсы. `Math.round()` работает с цифрами. Что в итоге тебе нужно?

Comment: нужно чтобы они прибавлялись

Comment: Почему числа не складываются? Всё же правильно.

Comment: Изначально это просто строка с числами и плюсами. Эту строку еще нужно обработать. Смотри мой окончательный вариант

Comment: `s = s.replace(/(\+)+/g, '$1')` можно удалить, если нужно просто сложить числа

Comment: @EzioMercer, я оставил это преобразование как преобразование строки. Т.с. для полноты картины...

Comment: @ksa Я так и понял :) Просто увидев чего хочет автор, понял что это бессмысленно делать. Можно сделать эту строку комментарием, ну или пихнуть регулярку в `split` [подробнее тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1486612/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5#comment2663967_1486624)

Comment: @EzioMercer, раз ты так настаиваешь...

Answer (score 2):

Удалить лишние плюсы можно вот-так:

```js
const s = '50+50++50+70+50+50+++50';


function delPlus(s) {
  const items = s.split('+');
  tmp = "";
  for (let item of items) {
    if (item) {
      tmp += item;
      tmp += "+";
    }
  }
  return tmp.slice(0, -1);
}


console.log(delPlus(s));
```

Если нужна сумма тогда еще проще:

```js
const s = '50+50++50+70+50+50+++50';


function sum(s) {
  const items = s.split('+');
  tmp = 0;
  for (let item of items) {
    if (item) {
      tmp += parseInt(item);
    }
  }
  return tmp;
}


console.log(sum(s));
```

Comment: `split` может принимать в качестве аргумента регулярное выражение. Тогда ваш алгоритм сводится к `return s.split(/\++/).join('+')` и не нужно проверять каждый элемент массива на пустоту и потом из конечной строки возвращать подстроку. Единнственное, регулярки медленные (на больших наборах данных), но в таких простых задачах для упрощения логики вполне полезны